# How to debug IE9 HTA?

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer-9, hta

Has anyone gotten a debugger attached to mshta.exe after installing IE9? (64bit or WOW64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on a Vista x64, so I have to contend with the 32bit/64bit barrier.

HTA

- c:\windows\system32\mshta.exe
  (mshta32)
- c:\windows\syswow64\mshta.exe
  (mshta64)

Launching

- "mshta32 foo.hta" may use mshta32 or mshta64 depending on what is associated with HTA
- the same goes if "mshta64 foo.hta" is used
- "cmd /C start foo.hta" would have the same affect.

Debugger

- MS Script Editor (from Office XP/2003) for JS debugging in IE/HTA

Normally I would use the `debugger` keyword to initiate the launching of the debugger, however with IE9, it doesn't seem to do that anymore. I must launch the debugger first, attach to the mshta.exe process manually (only supports 32bit). Then everything appears to work fine!

**EDIT:**

With coworkers, different machine have exhibited different behaviors:

- `debugger` keyword works fine
- Connecting to `MSHTA.EXE` from the debugger doesn't work

**I haven't yet found a silver bullet.**

Answer (score 3):

If you have Visual Studio, go to `Tools -> Attach to Process` and attach to the `MSHTA.EXE` process.  Then pick `Script` as the target to debug.

Comment: You will also need to enable script debugging on IE from the Tools => Internet Options => Advanced Tab => Browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'Stop' statement. This should raise the debugger dialog

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Finally pieced together how to debug using Visual Studio from two sources

1. Turn on script debugging through Internet Explorer, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z959x58c.aspx) and [here](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/maikkoster/archive/2009/03/25/debugging-vbscript-and-jscript-in-vbs-js-wsf-and-hta-files.aspx)
2. Start up Visual Studio. Click on Debug -> Attach to Process
3. Run the .hta file and select the running process from the Attach to Process dialog